# Don't print last segment of URL

Tags: php

I have some php which prints a url. Can I contain this with PHP to leave off the last segment?

So this:

```
www.mysite.com/name/james
```

would become this:

```
www.mysite.com/name
```

I'm using expression engine so the code is just {site_url}.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$url = (substr($url, -1) == '/') ? substr($url, 0, -1) : $url; // remove trailing slash if present
$urlparts = explode('/', $url); // explode on slash
array_pop($urlparts); // remove last part
$url = implode($urlparts, '/'); // put it back together
```

Comment: wouldnt it need to be `$url = implode('/',$urlparts);`?  without the glue string, it will put the pieces together without the slash and you would get `www.mysite.comname`

Comment: How do I apply this code? The {site_url} creates a url on the page so I can use it to make a link. I was hoping there would be some code I could put around the {site_url}. Thanks

Comment: @jdln {site_url} is some template magic, before your URL goes there, you can format it.

Comment: So if I place the code before the url, will it only affect that one? Does it need to be exactly before or will it just effect the next url in the page? Thanks

Comment: I think ive figured it out. Thanks a lot